Ubuntu 20.04 dotnet 8 swagger works but not API
I've been trying to make a sample API project work on Ubuntu with nginx. For this, i've done the following:

Bought domain and vps with ubuntu 20.04
Installed dotnet 8 runtime, nginx and mongodb
Did necessary nginx configuration changes to point to the dotnet API application in port 5000.

I've been successful in opening the swagger UI from browser (www.mysite.com/swagger/index.html)
However, when I try to make requests to the actual APIs (e.g. www.mysite.com/api/Auth/GetToken), I'm getting internal server error. These are running fine in my windows dev system.
I've checked nginx's error log (/var/www/log/error.log) but there's nothing there.
Below is the nginx sites-enabled and sites-available default configuration:
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

I could apply logging but I don't know where exactly to place it.
I would be happy to share any other file/config if required.
Thanks.

Please try to enable logging in your application. And I guess there are some issue when you call this Auth/GetToken method, like db connection issue.

@JasonPan sorry for the late response. I did find out the issue, it was with the JWT injection (which works in DEV env btw). Since this was only for learning purpose, I installed VS code and tried to debug but the project wouldn't run with lots of errors. At that point, I just gave up. The amount of time I spent trying to make win -> linux work for dotnet core just wasn't worth it. I'd be better off getting a windows vps, even though
a bit pricier.
